# Force Postfix to use TLS for MySQL Connection?

Tags: mysql, ssl, postfix, mariadb

## The Problem

I cannot figure out how to force Postfix to use a TLS connection to MySQL.  I **can** manually connect from the Postfix server to the MySQL server with TLS as the postfix user, so there's nothing broken with MySQL authentication.  The problem is clear:  Postfix isn't requesting TLS for the MySQL connection.

Versions:

- OS:  CentOS 7
- Postfix:  2:2.10.1-6.el7 and 2:3.2.4-1.gf.el7
- MySQL (MariaDB):  5.5.56

## How I Got Here

I have been searching all over the web, including the various StackExchange sites, for an answer to this question.  I have read the Postfix and MySQL documentation at great length, repeatedly.  The best answer I've found is one I reject as unnecessarily complicated:  "*Set up an SSH tunnel between your Postfix and MySQL servers, then connect over it.*"  There has to be a way to instruct Postfix to use TLS (SSL) encryption with the MySQL client.

Before we explore the setup, let me make this firm:  **My mail server setup works perfectly well without MySQL TLS**.  I am successfully using TLS for SMTPS and IMAPS and that has *nothing to do with my question*.  Mail is being transported securely both in and out of my network except MySQL connections between Postfix and the MySQL server are unencrypted.  Except for the exposed Postfix-MySQL link, there are no problems whatsoever with my mail infrastructure.

However, due to changing security requirements, I must update my existing infrastructure to encrypt all MySQL connections.  Setting up TLS for MySQL connections was easy.  **Manual tests show that MySQL clients can successfully connect over a TLS-encrypted link from all permitted hosts**.  So, the MySQL TLS setup is also solid and working for everything **except Postfix**.

## What I've Tried

#### Relevant configuration on the Postfix Server:

**/etc/postfix/main.cf**

Reduced to just one of several connections to keep the material as specific as possible.

```
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/lookup_aliases.cf
proxy_read_maps = $virtual_alias_maps
```

**/etc/postfix/lookup_aliases.cf**

Credentials and hostnames obfuscated.

```
hosts = mysql-server.domain.tld
user = postfix
password = *****
dbname = mail
option_file = /etc/my.cnf.d/client.cnf
option_group = client
tls_verify_cert = yes
query = SELECT goto FROM alias WHERE address = '%s' AND active = '1'
```

**/etc/my.cnf**

This file is untouched.  I'm including it only to show that the next configuration file is properly included into the MySQL Client configuration.

```
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d
```

**/etc/my.cnf.d/client.cnf**

```
[client]
ssl = true
```

### Successful -- MANUAL -- MySQL TLS Connection Output From the Postfix Server as the postfix User

Note in particular that TLS is successfully employed:

```
# hostname -f
mail.domain.tld

# sudo -u postfix mysql -h mysql-server.domain.tld -u postfix -p mail
Enter password:
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 72
Server version: 5.5.56-MariaDB MariaDB Server

Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [mail]> \s
--------------
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.56-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Connection id:     72
Current database:  mail
Current user:      postfix@mail.domain.tld
SSL:           Cipher in use is DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Current pager:     stdout
Using outfile:     ''
Using delimiter:   ;
Server:            MariaDB
Server version:        5.5.56-MariaDB MariaDB Server
Protocol version:  10
Connection:        mysql-server.domain.tld via TCP/IP
Server characterset:   latin1
Db     characterset:   utf8
Client characterset:   utf8
Conn.  characterset:   utf8
TCP port:      3306
Uptime:            1 hour 27 min 23 sec

Threads: 1  Questions: 271  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 13  Flush tables: 2  Open tables: 39  Queries per second avg: 0.051
--------------

MariaDB [mail]> \q
Bye
```

#### Relevant configuration on the MySQL Server:

MySQL Grants

Notice that TLS (SSL) is REQUIREd but otherwise the permissions are relatively lax until I sort this TLS connection problem out:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'postfix'@'10.0.101.%';
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for postfix@10.0.101.%                                                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'postfix'@'10.0.101.%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*SOMEPASSWORDHASH' REQUIRE SSL |
| GRANT SELECT ON `mail`.* TO 'postfix'@'10.0.101.%'                                                  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

#### Logs

*Postfix Connection Fails When REQUIRE SSL*

Even though the manual command-line test of the MySQL TLS connection SUCCEEDS here, Postfix still won't use MySQL TLS.

The MySQL General Log:

```
180217 14:45:15       16 Connect   postfix@mail.domain.tld as anonymous on mail
      16 Connect   Access denied for user 'postfix'@'mail.domain.tld' (using password: YES)
```

The Postfix Log:

```
Feb 19 19:22:55 mail postfix/cleanup[11951]: warning: proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/lookup_aliases.cf lookup error for "root@mail.domain.tld"
Feb 19 19:22:55 mail postfix/cleanup[11951]: warning: E2CCA2069823: virtual_alias_maps map lookup problem for root@mail.domain.tld -- message not accepted, try again later
```

*Postfix Connection SUCCEEDS When REQUIRE SSL is Removed*

This is Postfix successfully connecting after changing the permission from REQUIRE SSL to REQUIRE NONE.  However, the connection is **not encrypted**.

```
180217 15:17:21       26 Connect   postfix@mail.domain.tld as anonymous on mail
          26 Query show databases
          26 Query show tables
          26 Field List    admin
          26 Field List    alias
          26 Field List    alias_domain
          26 Field List    config
          26 Field List    domain
          26 Field List    domain_admins
          26 Field List    fetchmail
          26 Field List    log
          26 Field List    mailbox
          26 Field List    quota
          26 Field List    quota2
          26 Field List    vacation
          26 Field List    vacation_notification
          26 Query select @@version_comment limit 1
```

## Conclusion

All I need is for Postfix to honor `ssl = true` for its MySQL client connections.  Please let me know if you need any further information.

### Update:

After posting this question, I discovered through a more careful read that Postfix versions older than 2.11 do not support reading MySQL configuration files, at all.  As such, it is impossible to configure the vendor-supplied version of Postfix (version 2.10) to use MySQL TLS.  I feel for a poor wording choice in the Postfix documentation, where the upper portion of [the Postfix documentation for MySQL configuration](http://www.postfix.org/MYSQL_README.html) reads:

```
Postfix 3.1 and earlier don't read [client] option group settings unless a non-empty option_file or option_group value are specified. To enable this, specify, for example "option_group = client".
```

The author failed to spell out:

```
These options are ignored for Postfix 2.10 and earlier.  Postfix 2.11 through 3.1 don't read [client] option group settings unless a non-empty option_file or option_group value are specified. To enable this, specify, for example "option_group = client".
```

So, I upgraded Postfix on CentOS 7 from the vendor-supplied version 2.10 to the [GhettoForge Plus supplied](http://ghettoforge.org/index.php/Usage) version 3.2.  I did install the additional `postfix3-mysql` package.  I had high hopes but those have been dashed.  Now, even with Postfix 3.2, it **still won't connect to MySQL over a TLS link**.

I have attempted both `option_file = /etc/my.cnf` (should be the default and unnecessary) and `option_file = /etc/my.cnf.d/client.cnf` to no avail.

I even attempted to force Postfix to consider TLS by adding `tls_verify_cert = yes`.  This also had no effect.  Note that the certificate name does match, so this verification will pass if it is ever actually attempted.

Comment: Have you tried to set the MySQL Client configuration file in `/etc/postfix/lookup_aliases.cf`?
`echo "option_file = /etc/my.cnf.d/client.cnf" >> /etc/postfix/lookup_aliases.cf`
I looked into it with strace and noticed, that postfix never read my my.cnf.

When I forced it with `option_file`, postfix read the file.

Comment: @CookieCrash I had a similar idea and tried both `option_file = /etc/my.cnf` and `option_file = /etc/my.cnf.d/client.cnf`.  Neither helped.  I also considered an SELinux issue, but /var/log/audit.log is clean.

Comment: I took a much closer look at the [postfix documentation surrounding the MySQL capabilities](http://www.postfix.org/mysql_table.5.html) and -- very much to my dismay -- discovered that Postfix versions < 2.11 simply don't bother to read the MySQL client configuration, at all; the option_* and tls_* settings aren't even supported.  Well, CentOS 7 only offers Postfix 2.10.  In short, **there is no possible way to force Postfix < 2.11 to use TLS for MySQL connections on CentOS 7** outside of using non-base, 3rd party repositories or building Postfix from source to obtain version 2.11 or newer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Synopsis

In order to establish a MySQL TLS connection from Postfix, you need:

1. **Postfix version 2.11 or newer**.  CentOS 7 only provides [Postfix version 2.10](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/).  You must acquire an upgrade for Postfix from non-CentOS means.  I elected to use the `postfix3` and `postfix3-mysql` packages from [GhettoForge Plus](http://ghettoforge.org/index.php/Usage) because it seems [well recommended by the CentOS community](https://wiki.centos.org/de/AdditionalResources/Repositories/).
2. Set **within your `mysql_table` configuration files** either:

   1. At least one permissible `tls_ciphers` setting;
   2. A client-side TLS certificate and its matching private key, **signed by a Certificate Authority that is common to both the MySQL server and your Postfix client**; or
   3. both.
3. **Do not rely on setting these in your /etc/my.cnf or /etc/my.cnf.d/* files!**  The Postfix MySQL code doesn't read those files to determine whether to establish a MySQL TLS connection; they are parsed much too late.  The **only** way to instigate Postfix to open a MySQL TLS connection is to specify the TLS settings within your `mysql_table` configuration files.  Period.

## How I Got Here

I finally resorted to reading through the Postfix 3.2 source code.  Lines 653-658 of src/global/dict_mysql.c were especially informative.

## Final Solution

If you want to emulate the behavior of `ssl = true`, you just need to add a line similar to the following to your `mysql_table` configuration files:

```
tls_ciphers = TLSv1.2
```

Our configuration requires that only TLS 1.2 be used -- and had already long been enforced in the configuration of our MySQL servers, so it didn't automatically occur to me to also enforce it on the clients -- but you are free to add other ciphers if your organization tolerates older ciphers.

Note that we are perfectly happy not using client-side certificates.  We use other means to guard and actively monitor our database connections; we just don't want additional complexity.

### Alternative Solution

If you would rather enforce that only known, trusted clients connect to your MySQL servers -- and you cannot do so through other policy enforcement mechanisms like tight firewalls, strict password complexity, password rotation periodicity, connection auditing, and such -- then you can also use client-side certificates via these additional settings in your `mysql_table` configuration files:

```
tls_key_file = /path/to/private.key
tls_cert_file = /path/to/public.certificate
tls_CAfile = /path/to/common.CA.certificate # OR tls_CApath = /path/to/CA-and-intermediate-chain-certificates/
```

Again, setting these in /etc/my.cnf or /etc/my.cnf.d/* **won't help**.  These files aren't parsed until *after* the connection type (TLS or non-TLS) has *already been decided*.

If you opt to use client-side certificates, **enforce them at the server**!  You **do not** need client-side certificates when all you want is to encrypt MySQL traffic; instead, just use the `tls_ciphers` alternative, above.  Adding client-side certificates enables MySQL to verify that a connecting client is both already known and trusted but **only if you tell MySQL how to do so**!  It won't guess and relying only on the presence of a common CA between client and server is only a partial implementation of this powerful tool.  If you are interested in this MySQL security model, I found at least one [How To guide that provides good examples for how to employ client certificate validation](https://icicimov.github.io/blog/database/MySQL-SSL-and-client-certificates-authentication/).

Comment: This is all very helpful; nicely researched! That said, how did you discover the `tls_ciphers` setting for the `mysql_table` configuration files -- only from studying the source? I can't find any documentation regarding that option.

Comment: @BenJohnson Indeed, I figured this out by carefully reading through the source code.  It is unfortunate that the documentation is incomplete.