# Connecting postfix to mysql with ssl

Tags: mysql, debian, postfix

I've been trying to get the correct recipe of settings to allow postfix to connect to mysql where ssl is required.  So far I have the following config that is not working:

```
user = mysqluser
password = XXX
hosts = secure-mysql-db.example.com
dbname = mail
query = SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE email='%s'
tls_CAfile = /path/to/mysql-ca.crt
```

When using this config, I get the following error

> postfix/cleanup[1317842]: warning: connect to mysql server
> secure-mysql-db.example.com: SSL connection error: No such file or
> directory

I have indeed confirmed that the file is accessible.  Connecting using the same credentials via the command line works as expected.

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

**Update**

After reviewing [Force Postfix to use TLS for MySQL Connection?](https://serverfault.com/questions/897693/force-postfix-to-use-tls-for-mysql-connection), I've added the following:

```
user = mysqluser
password = XXX
hosts = secure-mysql-db.example.com
dbname = mail
query = SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE email='%s'
tls_ciphers = TLSv1.3
tls_CAfile = /path/to/mysql-ca.crt
```

Now I'm getting the following error:

> SSL connection error: no cipher match

I have indeed confirmed that the connect does work to the database:

```
mysql -h secure-mysql-db.example.com -p -u postfix mail

MySQL [mail]> \s
--------------
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.5.15-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Connection id:          487933
Current database:       mail
Current user:           mysqluser@192.168.0.143
SSL:                    Cipher in use is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Current pager:          stdout
Using outfile:          ''
Using delimiter:        ;
Server:                 MySQL
Server version:         8.0.26 MySQL Community Server - GPL
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             secure-mysql-db.example.com via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    utf8mb4
Db     characterset:    utf8mb4
Client characterset:    utf8mb3
Conn.  characterset:    utf8mb3
TCP port:               3306
Uptime:                 17 days 7 hours 25 min 45 sec
```

I'm running Postfix 3.5.13 on Debian 11.5

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force Postfix to use TLS for MySQL Connection?](https://serverfault.com/questions/897693/force-postfix-to-use-tls-for-mysql-connection)

Comment: @AlexD Thanks for that reference - got me new errors, but still no solution trying various combinations of settings and certs.